# Jquery select events

Tags: jquery

i am working with a select. I want to trigger and event when the user select a value.

I am using the event "change", the problem is that if a user open the select but choose the same option that is selected, the triggers doesn't fire.

Is there a way to capture the event when a user select an option independently if the option is the same than is the one that was selected?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to re-fire an event if the selection does not change?

Answer (score 4):

You can catch both the change and click events using the bind method. This should allow you to catch most keyboard and mouse interactions

```
$('selector').bind('click change',function() {})
```

Comment: If i put change the problem is that is fired when i click on the select to see the options.

Comment: How about keyup and mouseout? 

What is the final aim of this, As bears says above why do you need to re-fire an event if the value hasn't changed?

Comment: I can't speak for Patxi, but in my application, choosing an option in the top select propagates that value to other selects on the page.  The reverse is not true (choosing an option elsewhere will not change the top select's selected value).  I've found that if a user changes the top select to '1' and then changes a few of the other selects to '2' but then decides that he actually does want them all to be '1', he may "re-select" '1' (which would already be the selected option) at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether it's a cross-browser solution but something like this:

```
$("#mySelect option").click(function() {
    // do sth
});
```

Works well in Opera/Firefox.

Comment: I have a lot of selects in the same page and i think this option would not be efficient. But thanks.

Comment: You can have many `select`s - I don't know why it could be a problem? Just use correct selector.

Comment: Concur with @Crozin. The above example would not cause any conflicts as the hash mark denotes an id. Only one element should have that individual id.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It does exactly what the question asks (and without offering a solution that doesn't act the way the Patxi wants and then questioning the reason for the original question).  I can't imagine why there would be an efficiency problem unless you have several selects with no ids.  If for whatever reason you don't want to add an id to the select(s) then you may need to take a bit of a performance hit, but it probably won't be much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option you need is "click" instead of change.

Comment: This will not work as expected because it will cause the event to fire as soon as you open the select to choose your option.  Therefore if you plan to use the selection of a user in your code, it could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need.
Below is not the answer but a trick.

In my case, i change the value of select box after get value of it.

```
$("selector").on('change', function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val().trim();
  if (selectedValue == 'EXPECTED_VALUE') {
    //do somethings
  }
  //change the value, so next time when you choose same option 
  //again the change event can be trigger
  $(this).val('OTHER_VALUE');  
}
```

The OTHER_VALUE may be is EXPECTED_VALUE with an extra space. Example: EXPECTED_VALUE = 'foo' then OTHER_VALUE = 'foo '. So you get same value when you get selectedValue by

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val().trim();
```

I just want to comment but i have not enough reputation :D

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){

  if($(this).val() == "week"){
    //trigger here
  }
});
<select id="selectID">
    <option>week</option>
</select>
```